# Could not initialize wmi interface

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I made a program in vb.net using visual studio 2013 and while creating a user for database to use inside the program I run into this problem. I created a user with permissions that are required for me from this video: [CLICK ME](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEuq6E7Z2l0)

and I am getting this error: **could not initialize wmi interface workbench.wmiopensession(); could not connect to target machine.**

I don't know where to post about this problem but can someone tell me how to fix it? I need this fixed this month.

I am a beginner with mysql and mine mysql is newer version than that video.

Bonus information:
I can't rly give you anything everything i done was from that video and mysql is fresh installed i do not use firewall and i do have port forward on mysql. If you know what you need to know tell me.

Problem: i need to have wmi enabled. How do i enable it? i am using windows 8.1 pro SOLVED but still not fixed

Comment: With respect, you haven't provided nearly enough information for us to help you troubleshoot this problem.  But,`wmiopensession()` probably doesn't relate directly to a database connection.  Read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394603.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I think i don't have wmi enabled thats the problem. How to enable it?

Comment: Crap. I think it need to have windows server to enable that...

Comment: NEW error. When i press ok on the error i get i receive another error too that say Current profile has no WMI enabled. How do i enable it on the profile?

Comment: I bought mysql cloud hosting if this work i don't need this anymore.

Answer (score 1):

WMI is available since Windows XP already, IIRC. And it is available on normal Windows machines, not only servers. You only need to enable it on the target machine. And make sure you use a wmi user that is member of the **local** admin group otherwise configuration becomes a nightmare with all the required rights. I don't say it's impossible to make another user be able to use the wmi features needed in MySQL Workbench, but it's a lot simpler to configure with a local admin.

Comment: Thanks i was going to buy cloud server but now that i don't need it a very nice thing. But how do i enable it? i can't find it that show how to do that. I am using windows 8.1

Comment: Control Panel / Programs / Turn Windows Features On and Off / Simple Network Management Protocol / WMI SNMP Provider.   As this answer says, on the *target* machine or machines.

Comment: Ok i did that. But that still dosen't fix my problem... WHAT DOES THIS MYSQL NEED. Everything is by default settings....

Comment: Ok. I need to add the user. Where do i find the user to add it in the computer manager/services/wmi/security ?